WebMvcTagsContributor Depricated, what is alternative to this
Anyone give the solution for, alternative way to implement WebMvcTagsContributor with overriding getTags() and getLongRequestTags() methods.
As am migreating springboot from 2.x.x to 3.2.0, Need alternative solution to the above issue to implement

Have you read the migration guide? There's a section about this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#tag-providers-and-contributors-migration.

Yes, I gone through the guide but I need complete transition for getTags() and getLongRequestTags()
